# Move file with SQL Server script remote

Tags: sql-server, file, transfer, rdp

Please, can you help me with this problem?

How to use SQL Server remotely (rdp) and move a file with a script?

Comment: Very unclear ..... do you want to move a file to a remote SQL Server to be used there? Do you want to use SQL Server on a remote server to move files around? You need to be more precise and more accurate in your problem description

Comment: Using sqlserver in the first server, you transfer a file to the second server to access the second server from within itself. The first server data server is set up and on the second server of the application or database can extract the file. To use

Comment: I'm sorry that makes absolutely no sense. Why do you want to use RDP? You can use `xp_cmdshell` to do file level stuff but it is not recommended.

Comment: I want to go through Sqlserver Transfer an Excel file to another server because I do not have any access and there through Mysql I'll get it import

Comment: Does the "SQL Server" or "SQL Server Agent" *service account* have access? if not then you don't have access and you won't be able to do it

Comment: Yes must have access

Comment: I think we have a communication issue. I can't see the question coming to a logical conclusion

Answer (score 0):

***SQL Server is a database engine - it does not mean that it can perform file-based operations - that's not what it's designed for - the use of RDP is a misconception for the job.
You can use xp_cmdshell to do file level jobs, run cmd commands, but access to two servers is important, but not recommended.
This is possible through ftp transfer in SSIS, suppose you can create an SSIS packet and run it from SQL Serve.
There are several methods
Replication
Linked server
SSIS packages
, ...***